# Unable to change a text property for an org-mode link

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have the following at the top of an `org-mode` buffer:

```
[[aaa][bbb]]
(add-text-properties 1 13 '(help-echo "zzz"))
```

When I execute the list expression on the second line and hover the mouse of the link, I still get the help echo `"LINK: aaa"`, not the expected `"zzz"`.

**UPDATE:** I used edebug-trace and found that org-mode runs its code after I run mine and reverts the property back. I will have to use advising function, or, is there another way?

Comment: It may behoove you to inspect and consider modifying `org-activate-bracket-links` to suit your needs, as that is the function that is likely conflicting with the text-properties that you are trying to apply.  The function `org-activate-plain-links` also has text-properties that you may wish to modify.  [FYI:  I found it helpful to slightly change the regexp for bracketed links to obtain better highlighting of different sections of the links, and the section I modified was in `org-make-link-regexps` -- it's not necessary for your question, but I thought I would mention it.]

Comment: what are you really trying to do? You can define your own link with tooltips pretty easily. For example, see http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2016/11/04/New-link-features-in-org-9/#org4d40e92.

Comment: @JohnKitchin Thank you for the great link!

Comment: @lawlist I thought it was a bad practice to modify an existing function in `org-mode`, because someone may rely on some property of the original function in the future...

Comment: In `org-mode` 9 (that does *not* ship with latest stable Emacs release -- i.e., Emacs 25.2.1), the text-properties for links can be set with the function `org-link-get-parameter` which the user can customize with the variable `org-link-parameters`.  This cannot be done with `org-mode` 8.2.10 that ships with the latest Emacs stable release.  Thus, a user with `org-mode` that is `<` version 9 would either need to modify the undesired text-property after the fact (with advice or something), or the desired behavior can be hard-coded.  *bad-practice* versus hard-wiring desired behavior is opinion.